# I am unable to upload video to youtube using node js

Tags: node.js, youtube

i am trying to upload a video to youtube using nodejs and thn i will implement a frontend also 
the problem is i have done all steps such as authentication etc. I have also obtained the access token and refresh token and stored it in my database.
but whn i retrieve the access token and use it to upload my video it is giving me error 401 or login required. i have included my upload video code below

```
    export const uploadfile = (req, res) => {
console.log('QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ')
const fileSize = fs.statSync("video.mp4").size;
console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!');
const youtube = google.youtube({
    version: 'v3',
    });
Organizations
.get(req.org._id)
.then(result=>{
    let authtoken = result.services.youtube.oAuth.access_token
    authenticate().then(access_token => {
        console.log('**********^^^^^^^^^',access_token)

        const ch = youtube.videos.insert(
            {   
                part: 'id,snippet,status',
                notifySubscribers: false,
                requestBody: {
                snippet: {
              title: 'Node.js YouTube Upload Test',
              description: 'Testing YouTube upload',
            },
            status: {
              privacyStatus: 'private',
            },
          },
          media: {
            body: fs.createReadStream("video.mp4"),
          },

            },
            {
                onUploadProgress: evt => {
                    const progress = (evt.bytesRead / fileSize) * 100;
                    readline.clearLine(process.stdout, 0);
                    readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, null);
                    process.stdout.write(`${Math.round(progress)}% complete`);
                  },
            },
            console.log('**********')
        );

    });
```

Comment: which package you're using ?

Comment: i am using the googleapi for node js